# How do I create a name generator?

Tags: java, random, numbers

I am creating a program that prompts a first and last name then prints a string composed of the first letter of the user’s first name, followed by the first five characters of the user’s last name, followed by a random number in the range 10 to 99.

I know how to prompt for the name and find the random number but I'm not sure how to

"print a string composed of the first letter of the first name, followed by the first five letters of the last name."

Can anyone help me? I am a very elementary Java programmer.

So I am really close to finishing this but it keeps saying "illegal start of expression" for line 55 and I can't figure it out. Here is my code, sorry, I know it's a mess:

```
Random generator = new Random();

int num1;

num1 = generator.nextInt(10-99);
```

**line 55: public String substring;** <<<

```
String result;


System.out.println("Result:" + (beginIndex) + (firstname.substring(0,1) + lastname. substring (0,5)) + (num1) );
```

Comment: This sounds like homework, and if so you should tag it as such.

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Comment: What happens if the last name is 4 characters or less?

Answer (score 8):

Seems like homework to me, so I will give a hint. look for the method [substring()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) and [charAt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) for the first part, and the [Random class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) for the second.

Comment: @MByD +1 nice clear suggestions. Though I must say that personally I would go with [Math.random()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) instead of Random class.

Comment: @Boro - thanks, I usually use the `Random` class, because I prefer to ignore extra calculations where the work has already been done, but it's not that important for me :)

Comment: Thank you. It is homework of a supposedly non-major computer science course but my teacher failed to point us in the right direction of help from our book. I can easily look this up and figure it out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MByD now I am thinking that actually in my codes dealing with random numbers, e.g. dice throw, I could have easily just go with `Random.nextInt(xx)` yet I used the `Math.random()` then multiply then cast. Well good that I am using utility methods, will be easier to modify the code now :) I must say I was wrong using `Math.random()` in these situation. Thanks MByD.

Comment: @Jessica:  Don't forget to mark MByD's answer 'correct' (something to do with clicking the 'tick' box beside the answer).  That will move it to the top of the answer list and make it easier to find later.

Answer (score 1):

I am a .NET developer so I can't help you with the syntax but you would need to grab the first char of the first name, usually accessible via an indexer - firstName.charAt(0), and a substring of the second one that ranges from the first character (ordinal 0) to the 5th character (ordinal 4), likely something like lastName.substring(0, 4); and concatenate these two strings -

```
concatenatedName = firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.substring(0, 4);
```

Comment: +1 for giving good suggestion and writing correctly 'Java style' method names. Without those ugly capital letters on start of each method name :)

Comment: :) Thanks, obviously have to disagree with you on the ugly bit but this is a religious war for another time and place.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [String.substring()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: The method name is all lower-case.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;


class Name {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Random rnd = new Random(); // Initialize number generator

        String firstname = "Jessica"; // Initialize the strings
        String lastname = "Craig";

        String result; // We'll be building on this string

        // We'll take the first character in the first name
        result = Character.toString(firstname.charAt(0)); // First char

        if (lastname.length() > 5)
            result += lastname.substring(0,5);
        else
            result += lastname; // You did not specify what to do, if the name is shorter than 5 chars

        result += Integer.toString(rnd.nextInt(99));


        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about giving you a negative point for your answer, but I decided against it. Why? You basically give away a solution for a homework question. Not a good thing to do, since it's better if OP tries to solve it him/herself. Second, you can't concatenate the number to a string implicitly in Java. Third, your program will crash if last name contains less than 5 characters.

Comment: @darioo I agree with you. You should not give a solution especially in homework questions. The whole point IMHO is to let the OP learn the solution, in a long run it is much better. It is such an old truth like heck itself :) There was once one guy talking something about giving a fish, but he didn't take the fish as he liked fishing, or something like that :)

Comment: @darioo As to your 'Second' remark you are mistaken in this case. You are not able to assign a number to a string without casting it. But you can always concatenate it. Since `x += y` is the same as `x = x + y` you have casting first before the assignment thus it will work fine.

Comment: @Boro: you're correct. I just tried it and it works. Surprised me a bit, since I didn't really expect it to work. You learn something new every day ;-) although I'd never want to see something like this in production code.

Comment: @darioo I just updated the answer, fixing the issues you mentioned. I know we should not be helping helpless students. Lets just hope OP reads about the topics and struggles - deleting the answer now would not make much sense, as OP probably already has read it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parentheses for println.

I would recommend removing all the parentheses around the string concats they just make it hard to read.

```
System.out.println("Result:" + beginIndex + firstname.substring(0,1) + lastname.substring(0,5) + num1 );
```

Also what happens if the user enters a last name with only 4 characters?

Answer (score 0):

See how easy it is? I gave 4 simple names which can be replaced with words and such. The "4" in the code represents the number of names in the String. This is about as simple as it gets. And for those who want it even shorter(all I did was decrease the spacing):

```
import java.util.*; 
public class characters{ 
public static void main(String[] args){
Random generate = new Random(); 
String[] name = {"John", "Marcus", "Susan", "Henry"};
System.out.println("Customer: " + name[generate.nextInt(4)]); }}
```